# Bold in RichtextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I've been working on my richtextbox but I ran into something weird...
I want to make the first word on everyline bold

using this code:

```
        RichTextBox bold = richTextBox1;
        foreach (string line in bold.Lines)
        {
            string name = line.Split(' ')[0];
            int srt = bold.Find(name);
            bold.Select(srt, name.Length);
            bold.SelectionFont = new Font(bold.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
```

But for some reason some lines are skipped.
From what I noticed it depends on what word the line starts with

e.g Name: gets skipped but Name1: is fine, the same happens with ProcessId, VirtualSize and WorkingSetSize.

[image: Example]

If any more explanation is required please tell me.

The lines are added like

```
richTextBox1.Text += "Name: "+ queryObj["Name"] + Environment.NewLine;
```

the function to make all first words bold is called after all the content is added to the richtextbox.

Comment: How are you adding the lines to the richtextbox?

Comment: I see you have all first words ending in a : . Can you try using  string name = line.Split(': ')[0]; instead?

Comment: Any reason why this is getting down voted?...

Comment: Stackoverflow is working like someone asking a question and smart people giving the answer. Answering an answer is like answering with a question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line...

```
int srt = bold.Find(name);
```

...is finding the first occurrence of the word that starts the line. If you look at the words that haven't been set bold then you will see that they all occur earlier in the rich text box.

Comment: That was it I can't believe I didn't think of that my self. Thanks a lot man :)
Fixed it by using int srt = bold.Find(line); instead.

Answer (score 0):

My richtextbox wasn't selecting all the occurrences if they weren't sent to my bolding function in the right order; so my fix includes checking that start (srt) is greater than 0 before starting the text selection. It goes something like this:

```
foreach (string line in bold.Lines)
{
    int srt = bold.Find(name);
    if (srt > 0)
    {
        bold.Select(srt, name.Length);
        bold.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(bold.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

And now it'll always select the first occurrence.

PS: `name` is a `string`, and `bold` is a `RichTextBox`.